# Move the focus to a DataGridView Cell - Finding the cell based on some value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I move the focus to a cell and highligh it based on text box value for example text box value.

The below code is used based on number of cell but I am looking for to select entered value in text box.

```
dgpay.CurrentCell = dgpay.Rows[2].Cells[0];
dgpay.Rows[2].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `CUrrentCell` first, then call [`BeginEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit(v=vs.110).aspx) by passing `true` as parameter to put the current cell in edit mode and select all the cell's contents. For example:

```
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0];
this.dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```

**Note:** For example if you want to find the first cell in `DataGridView` based on some value and select the cell and begin editing you can use such code:

```
var cell = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .SelectMany(x => x.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>())
                .Where(x => string.Format("{0}", x.FormattedValue) == textBox1.Text)
                .FirstOrDefault();
if (cell != null)
{
    this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
    this.dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
}
```

Comment: For example if you want to find the first cell in `DataGridView` based on some value and select the cell and begin editing, read the **Note** part. For more complicated cases (for example creating a find window) you may need a different mechanism to search.